# Firebase hosting config

Tags: firebase-hosting

I'm having difficultty migrating netlify.toml configuration to firebase.json.

The netlify config that works is:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/en/:splat"
  status = 200
  force = false
```

I tried to move over to firebase hosting, the config I put is:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "/*",
      "destination": "/en/*",
      "status": 200
    }],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried various permutations of the above but still unable to get it to work. When I deploy to firebase hosting my page only loads with the /en in front of the root url.

Any one know how I can get the same `netlify.toml` behaviour with `firebase.json`?

Repo can be found [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web.dev/blob/master/netlify.toml).